# Sharepoint 2010 - date list showing month/year only or blank

Tags: 2010

I have a date field which I want to display as month/year only OR leave it blank.

I've managed to get this to work

```
=TEXT(Date,"mmmm")&" "&YEAR(Date)
```

but how do I add a line saying that if the date field is blank, leave it blank?

It is defaulting to putting in December 1899.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way, but it works for me.

```
=IF(YEAR(Date)=1899;" ";YEAR(Date)&"/"&MONTH(Date))
```